# apt-cacher-ng for different distros OK?

Tags: debian, docker, apt-cache, apt-cacher-ng

Would setting up `apt-cacher-ng` in the host and serve it for different dockers running different distros be OK? E.g., even for a Ubuntu host servicing different versions of Debian?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear on what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: @RolandiXor, hmm... setting up apt-cacher-ng in the docker host and serve it for different docker clients running different distros than host, e.g.,  for a Ubuntu host servicing different versions of Debian.

Comment: I meant for you to edit your question. Also, you need to be a bit more descriptive if you're hoping to get an answer. As it is stands, it's a bit vague what you're asking.